# How can I change the image of my own

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android project using the link given below..

https://github.com/literakl/DressUp

All I wanted is to add the image of my own. I have included my image in the drawable folder. When I press a cloth it is not reflecting in the app.All I wanted is to change the clothes of my wish.

Comment: Can you please post your code

Comment: show me the efforts!@Anirudh

Comment: I have given the link. I'm not able to upload any images

Comment: Those are not **your** efforts, they're someone else's efforts. Voting to close.

Comment: code ??????????

Comment: Whose ever it may be... I'm just a beginner and I'm trying to learn

Comment: https://github.com/literakl/DressUp

Comment: You changed Json file Which is hear in lib....

Comment: No I haven't.. I don't know how to change it

Comment: but In This Json  File Has Path Of Image Name AND Also X and Y of Image

Comment: So how to add path of my image

Comment: Edit The Json File

Comment: and Change The Path As Your File

Comment: Even though I use the path of my image, only the icon changes in the app but the cloth remains same

Comment: Did U Try The above answer

Answer (score 1):

Edit The Json File Add Path Of Your Image

[image: Json File Image]

Comment: Should I have to paste my image in the assets folder

Comment: Yes Paste Image In Assets > Vimla >hres >

Comment: Even though I changed the path only the icon has changed not reflecting when I click the image

Comment: Delete This Four Images  Shouse.png Skirt.png top.png tishirt.png

Comment: Yes all done bro, not helping

Comment: U also Change The Main Image part.png

Comment: Is that important

Comment: I didn't change that

Comment: Yes.. Is Important

Comment: OK I'll try and do the same.. If don't get it I'll post it here